How to tweak font size and position of reference in quarto revealjs slide
This is my example code:
---
title: "test"
format:
  revealjs:
    footer: Institute of | Tarjae
---

<!-- Style and format of footer -->
<style>
.reveal .footer {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px -20px;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 16px;
    z-index: 2;
}
</style>

## Outcomes fake trial at 5 years[^1]

[^1]: Tarjae Ann Surg 2023

-   **LRF**: 12% (EXP) vs. 8% (STD) (P=0.07)

-   **LRR after R0/R1 resection**: 10% (EXP) vs. 6% (STD) (P=0.027)


Which gives this (without the red rectangle):

How can I change the position and font size of the text in the red rectangle?
I am able to control the footnote on the right bottom side with the css (taken from here). But I don't know how to control the [^1] reference?

That css worked for me, the first one to increase the size an the second one to change location to the right:
.reveal .slide aside .aside-footnotes {
    font-size: 30px;
}
.reveal .slide aside, .reveal .slide div.aside {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    color: #6f6f6f;
}

